# Padded data in recv() api

Tags: windows, sockets, visual-c++, tcp, udp

I am working on TCP client server application using c++.third party lib are now allowed in this project.

Here exchange between client server takes using well define protocol format.once the client receives the packet it will send it for parsing.I have protocol manager which will take care of the parsing activity.

I have following doubt
When the data arrives at client from the network, the OS buffers it until application calls recv() function.

So two message msg1 and msg2 arrives at the buffer a call to recv will return msg1+msg2. Now this may result in failure of the parsing activity.

My queries
1. whether above mentioned assumption is correct or not ?
2. If above mentioned assuption is correct then how can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revathy,

What you need to do here is make a fixed length packet or at-least fixed length header followed by variable length data.

The header should contain size of the packet. So In the recv function you always read the header bytes and decode the size of the packet and read the rest of the packet using another recv call.

This way even when your TCP layer buffers any number of packets you will be able to read it correctly

```
    unsigned char* pBuffer = NULL;
    pBuffer = new unsigned char[MESSAGE_HEADER_LENGTH];

    // reading header from socket
    int nRet = recv(sock,(char*)pBuffer,MESSAGE_HEADER_LENGTH,0);
    int nDataLen = //Read the packet length from pBuffer
    // reading body from socket

    unsigned char* pPacket = NULL;
    pPacket= new unsigned char[nDataLen ];
    nRet = recv(sock,(char*)pPacket ,nDataLen ,0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In TCP, you cannot see packet boundaries, so if both packets arrive before you get to call `recv()`, you will get both packets' contents in a single go.

In UDP, packet boundaries are preserved, so each call to `recv()` gives back one packet.

Comment: As we are working in tcp,plz give us solution to find the number of packets that we are receiving using recv() API.Also, will client always get full response or there is any chance for getting half of response in one sort and remaining half in another sort(for example : depending on buffer that we defined for recv() API)

Comment: It is entirely possible to be given half packets -- TCP assumes that you want to transfer a single stream of data. Any structure of that data needs to come out of the protocol (record structure, length fields or escape characters). What protocol are you implementing?